# $\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\mu(j)[\frac{n}{j}]=1$

Tags: number-theory

This is a problem from Intro to Arithmetic functions by Paul Mccarthy.

For all $n,\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\mu(j)[\frac{n}{j}]=1$.

Since $\mu$ is multiplicative, I know that only products of distinct primes count non-trivial terms. However I do not know how to handle $[\frac{n}{\prod_{i}p_i}']$ where $p_i$ are distinct and $\prod_ip_i\leq n$. $[x]$ is the greatest integer $n$ s.t. $n\leq x$.

How should I progress? The book has not talked about riemann zeta function yet. So I guess I am not allowed to convolve $\zeta$ with $\mu$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is indeed not a divisor sum. I can break the sum into two parts. One is a sum of divisors' contribution and the other one is not. In that way, I do not know how to deal with integer part. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: $$\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(j)\Bigl\lfloor\frac{n}{j}\Bigr\rfloor=\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(j)\sum_{j\mid i\le n}1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\mid i}\mu(j)$$

Answer (score 1):

For arithmetic functions we have the Dirichlet product
$$
\sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d)\nu(n/d)=1,
$$
where $\nu(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n$. This is proved here:

[Sum of Positive Divisors: $\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d)\nu(d)=1$ and $\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d)\sigma(d)=n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137971/sum-of-positive-divisors-sum-dn-mun-d-nud-1-and-sum-dn-mun-d?rq=1).

We also have (see the comment above, and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_M%C3%B6bius_Function_over_Divisors))
$$
\sum_{j\mid i}\mu(j)=\left\lfloor \frac{1}{i}\right\rfloor , 
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(j)\left\lfloor \frac{n}{j}\right\rfloor =\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\mid i}\mu(j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{1}{i}\right\rfloor =1.
$$