# Does the Riemann zeta function tell us about the order theoretic properties of the natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, order-theory, riemann-zeta, characteristic-functions

The classical [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) $\mu(n)$ fulfills the multiplicative inversion formula, e.g. [see this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83805/an-identity-involving-the-mobius-function). Now I see in the theory of [posets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset), they generalize the concept of that function, see [incidence algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra#Special_elements) and from this point of view, the previous definition is the case for the natural numbers and its order induced by divisibility.

In the last link, they also define a "zeta-function" $\zeta(x,y)$ for elements $x,y$ of a poset - I think that's just the boolean version of "$x\le y$" telling me if two numbers $x,y$ are appropriately ordered. There is [a formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) of how to obtain the inverse of such a $\zeta$ using $\mu$, and this appears to be the source of the equal names.

But I fail to see if this new function is otherwise the analog of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(z)$ (and other members of the [family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions) of continuous zeta functions). Does that analytic function also somehow represent a characteristic function for ordered intervals of numbers? How is the inversion formula a generalization of it, when the number theoretic $\zeta(z)$ doesn't even have two arguments?

Or can I maybe connect $\zeta(x,y)$ to the idea behind the Arithmetic and Dedekind zeta function, which know about the spaces (ideals..) which can be constructed from their domain?

Comment: I am not much familiar with incidence algebra, but my guess is that this $\zeta$ has no connection with Riemann zeta at all.